# How can I prove that $\phi'>0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the ODE

$\phi''-c\phi' + f(\phi) =0$

where $c\in\mathbb{R}$, $\phi(-\infty)=0$, $\phi(\infty)=1$ and $f$ is a smooth real valued function with $f(0)=0=f(1)$.

It's true that $\phi'>0$?

Could someone give a hint? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not.

Consider the phase-plane for the equivalent system
$$ \eqalign{\dot{x} &= y\cr
            \dot{y} &= c y - f(x)\cr}$$
For example, with $c = -1$ and $f(x) = -x+x^2$, $(0,0)$ is a saddle while
$(1,0)$ is a stable spiral, and the trajectory that comes out of $(0,0)$ as $t \to -\infty$ along the unstable manifold in the first quadrant is attracted to $(1,0)$, but $y = \dot{x}$ is not always positive.

[image]